# Spring boot 2.2.1- Unable to start embed tomcat(no errors in log)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-starter

Am working on a `Spring Boot` application having version `2.2.1RELEASE`.Application structure ,i have moved configuration into config folder as external configuration.Project structure should be like this

[image]

When i run my application its showing following log

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

2019-12-12 20:34:41.631  INFO 375592 --- [           main] c.g.h.x.app.services.api.erviceMain  : Starting ServiceMain v1.0 on host-4 with PID 375592 (D:\Service\target\Service-10.jar started by Administrator in D:\Service\target)
2019-12-12 20:34:41.636  INFO 375592 --- [           main] c.g.h.x.app.services.api.ServiceMain  : The following profiles are active: Service
2019-12-12 20:34:45.086  INFO 375592 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-12-12 20:34:45.477  INFO 375592 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 154ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
408  SybaseUnit  INFO   [main] openjpa.Enhance - You have enabled runtime enhancement, but have not specified the set of persistent classes.  OpenJPA must look for metadata for every loaded class, whi
ch might increase class load times significantly.
296  SybaseUnit  WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'SybaseUnit', root URL [file:/D:/Service/targetService-1.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not
 be available.
312  SybaseUnit  WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Could not create the optional validation provider. Reason returned: "A default ValidatorFactory could not be created."
2019-12-12 20:34:50.108  INFO 375592 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'SybaseUnit'
0  MssqlUnit  INFO   [main] openjpa.Enhance - You have enabled runtime enhancement, but have not specified the set of persistent classes.  OpenJPA must look for metadata for every loaded class, which
might increase class load times significantly.
0  MssqlUnit  WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'MssqlUnit', root URL [file:/D:/Service/target/Service-1.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be
available.
0  MssqlUnit  WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Could not create the optional validation provider. Reason returned: "A default ValidatorFactory could not be created."
2019-12-12 20:34:50.140  INFO 375592 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'MssqlUnit'
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com..manager.data).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2019-12-12 20:34:53.284  INFO 375592 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'TaskExecutor'
2019-12-12 20:34:53.328  INFO 375592 --- [           main] ca.uhn.fhir.util.VersionUtil             : HAPI FHIR version is: 1.4
2019-12-12 20:34:53.335  INFO 375592 --- [           main] ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext          : Creating new FHIR context for FHIR version [DSTU3]
2019-12-12 20:34:54.946  INFO 375592 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService
2019-12-12 20:34:55.343  INFO 375592 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'asyncExecutor'
2019-12-12 20:34:57.647  INFO 375592 --- [           main] c.g.h.x.app.services.api.ServiceMain  : Started ServiceMain in 19.208 seconds (JVM running for 21.409)
```

`Pom.xml` file having added following dependencies

```
 <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                      <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!-- <exclusion>
                      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion> -->
          </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                      <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

> I have tried following possible solutions.

- update and clean my projects.
- delete `.m2` repository
  and also refer following stack links.

1.[Spring boot application not starting embedded tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617885/spring-boot-application-not-starting-embedded-tomcat)

2.[Spring boot deployed on tomcat won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919593/spring-boot-deployed-on-tomcat-wont-start)

Didn't get any solution yet.

Note:-
have noticed two line in my log

```
2019-12-12 20:34:45.086  INFO 375592 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-12-12 20:34:45.477  INFO 375592 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 154ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
```

Comment: Can you please start your app with `--debug` and share the condition evaluation report that it produces?

Comment: Also, I can see OpenJPA in the logs, but no sign of it in your dependencies. Where is it coming from?

Comment: it is coming form a library project

Comment: --debug showing the same lo details

Comment: That doesn't sound right. `--debug` should cause quite a big change in the output. How did you set it?

Comment: You haven't shown the library project in your pom. It's very hard to diagnose a problem without the complete picture. Can you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the interfaces not being on the same level as the main class with the @SpringBootApplication annotation.

**Here is an example.**

[image]

**Notice that all sub-packages are on the same level as the @SpringBootApplication.**